How to make ESLint recognize type imports
I'm working on a large Vue3 app that has recently had ESLint + lint-staged added to it.
ESLint is giving me a parser error for any type imports.
So imports like this are fine:
import { Something } from 'whatever';

But imports like this elicit ESLint parser errors:
import type { Something } from 'whatever';

I'm using ESLint 9.12.0 with the new flat config, typescript-eslint 8.15.0, and TypeScript 5.6.3
Type imports are not particularly new so I'm surprised that this doesn't just work.
Here's my ESLint config:
export default tseslint.config(
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    tseslint.configs.recommended,
    ...pluginVue.configs['flat/recommended'],
);

I tried using the tsParser from @typescript-eslint/parser and adding this to my config, as recommended by the answer to another SO question with a similar (but not identical) parser-related ESLint question:
languageOptions: { 
    parser: tsParser,  
    parserOptions: {  
        ecmaFeatures: { 
            modules: true
        },
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        extraFileExtensions: ['.vue']
    },
},

But I reverted that because it also just didn't seem to work - every single .vue file stopped being linted at all.
The config I've used is pretty much the default config suggested by the official TypeScript-ESLint documentation. Nothing there suggests that type-only imports won't work.
Additionally, if I remove the type part from the import with the standard config shown above, it then tells me that it has to be a type import!
So I can't use type imports for type-only imports, and I can't not use type imports for type-only imports!

I was missing a small piece of config, which is mentioned on the eslint-plugin-vue documentation:
languageOptions: {
    parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
    }
}


Did you try to add this rules to your config :
  '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': [
    'error',
    {
      fixStyle: 'inline-type-imports',
    },
  ],

->The rule<-
EDIT
You shouldn't use the function tseslint to export your config it wasn't working forme, so I made it works like that.
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import vueParser from 'vue-eslint-parser';

export default [
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs['flat/recommended'],
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parser: vueParser,
      parserOptions: {
        parser: tseslint.parser,
      },
    },
  }


Hi, thanks, yes, I did try exactly the config you've specified, and I also tried just disabling the rule altogether with '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': 'off' and that didn't work either. The problem is that I'm seeing a parser error, not a rule break

What's the parser error ?

Sorry, it's just Parsing error: Unexpected token {.

The problem is probably relative to your Typescript version. Try rolling back in 5.5.4.

Thanks, I tried the version you specified and had the same issue. I also tried the latest TS version just in case (5.7.2) and still see the issue. I also tried not using the tseslint.config function as suggested, and that also didn't fix the issue.

Can you put your project on gihub or a small reproduction of it ?
